# Why does the tkinter QUIT2 widget require me to press it twice for it to activate?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from openpyxl import *
from tkinter import *

def inputGetter(str):
    print(str, end="")
    return input()



class StartPage(Frame):
    global app
    def say_hi(self):
        test = SecondPage(master=root)
        app.destroy()
        test.mainloop()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.QUIT = Button(self)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "QUIT"
        self.QUIT["fg"]   = "red"
        self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit

        self.QUIT.pack({"side": "left"})

        self.hi_there = Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello",
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi

        self.hi_there.pack({"side": "left"})

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

class SecondPage(Frame):
    global app
    def say_hi(self):
        print('test')

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.QUIT2 = Button(self)
        self.QUIT2["text"] = "QUIT2"
        self.QUIT2["fg"]   = "red"
        self.QUIT2["command"] =  self.quit

        self.QUIT2.pack({"side": "left"})

        self.hi_there = Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Second",
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi

        self.hi_there.pack({"side": "left"})

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

root = Tk()
app = StartPage(master=root)

app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

for some reason when I press the QUIT widget it works but the QUIT2 widget located in the SecondPage class it requires me to click it twice. what is wrong with the code that makes it do this?

cheers, Marc

Comment: As a general rule, you should call `mainloop()` exactly once in a tkinter program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You launch two mainloops, and thus require two call to 'quit' to leave your program.

1. Either you launch your script from the interpreter (implicit mainloop) or you call `root` or `app` mainloop in you main program (not visible in your example, but required somehow to see the first window).
2. You launch a 2<sup>nd</sup> mainloop in `StartPage.say_hi`

I am not sure of the behavior expected but it does result in two mailoops, and two calls to `quit` are required to leave both. If you remove `test.mainloop()` from `StartPage.say_hi`, your problem is gone.